# Why is step 2 of file to media migrate giving me missing bundle error?

Tags: media, migrations

I am following the instruction on this page : https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media/issues/3118471 , but with media of bundle document, not image.  I have my step 1 yml on this issue [How can i debug why files are not being created when using migrate files to media module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297243/how-can-i-debug-why-files-are-not-being-created-when-using-migrate-files-to-medi)
My nodes of type grants and step 1 files are being created as media correctly, however when i do step 2, using the yml below, I get this error :

Missing bundle for entity type node (/var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php:108)

```
id: migd8_grants_media_step2
label: grants Media Mapping
migration_group: cncs
source:
  key: migrate
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: grants

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:
  nid: nid
  changed: changed
  
  field_files:
    plugin: file_id_lookup
    source: field_files
    migration: migd8_grants_media_step1
    no_stub: true

migration_dependencies:
  optional:
  - migd8_node_grants
  - migd8_grants_media_step1
```

I made some changes as an experiment and started getting duplicate grants being created, one with the correct media files attached, and one without , these are the changes i made which caused the duplicates with one having the correct file attached:

```
id: migd8_grants_media_step2
label: grants Media Mapping
migration_group: cncs
source:
  key: migrate
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: grants

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:
  nid: nid
  changed: changed
  title: title
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: grants
  field_files:
    plugin: file_id_lookup
    source: field_files
    migration: migd8_grants_media_step1
    no_stub: true

migration_dependencies:
  optional:
  - migd8_node_grants
  - migd8_grants_media_step1
```

Comment: Does the content type **grants** exist in both, the D7 and the D8 site? Seems like perhaps it doesn't exist on one of the sites.

Comment: Hmmm in D7 & D8 edit the Grants content type and [check that the machine name](https://i.imgur.com/81RLH89.png) is indeed grants for both. Also check that in [D8 the files field has a field type of entity reference](https://i.imgur.com/fJgCWlk.png) (which should be referencing  Media) and its not a field type of file.

Comment: The field names are correct , I made some changes and i started getting duplicate grants, one with the files attached correctly and the other without .  i put the yml that i made that causes those duplicates in the description above, one with the correct media attached.  how can i get that result without the duplicates?

Comment: actually the source in the original migration is a plugin : source:
  plugin: migd8_node_grants  does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in step2 i had to change it to this

```
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: grants
```